# NGINX how to set root dir depending on host

Tags: nginx

There is one nginx config for all websites on server.
All websites have one root directory except one that has another.
How to set root directory for that one host?

This config returns an error: `"root" directive is not allowed here`.

```
server {
    ...

    root "/webhome/$host/web";

    if ($host = site.example.com) {
        root /webhome/site.example.com/www;
    }
    
    ....
```

Also tried without success this:

```
location / {
    if ($host = site.example.com) {
        root /webhome/site.example.com/www;
    }
}
```

Comment: a single nginx config can have several server block though, or do you want them to all in a single server block?

Comment: Yes, now it is one server block, and it's quite large, don't want to copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is usually solved using several `server` blocks, you can use the [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block to evaluate `root` directive parameter value:

```
map $host $siteroot {
    site.example.com  /webhome/site.example.com/www;
    default           /webhome/$host/web;
}
server {
    root $siteroot;
    ...
```